# Perl Programming - How to match value of one column with another column in a given file

Tags: perl

I am a beginner with Perl programming. The problem I am working on right now is how to get the gene length from a text file. Text file contains the gene name (column 10), start site (column 6), end site (column 7). The length can be derived from the difference of column 6 and 7. But my problem is how to match the gene name (from column 10) with the corresponding difference derived from the difference of column 6 and column 7. Thank you very much!

```
open (IN, "Alu.txt");
open (OUT, ">Alu_lengthsubfam.csv");

while ($a = <IN>){
    @data = split (/\t/, $a);

$genelength = $data[7] - $data[6]++;
$subfam = $data[10]
}
    foreach $subfam (0...$#subfam){
        print OUT "$subfam, $genelength{$subfam}\n";
}
close (IN);
close (OUT)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please show sample input and expected output. Also, always `use strict; use warnings;` (and don't name your variables `$a` or `$b`, those are special).

Answer (score 1):

```sh
perl -F'\t' -lane'print $F[10], "\t", $F[7]-$F[6]' \
    < Alu.txt > Alu_lengthsubfam.csv
```